# Python RSA read config keys from INI file

Tags: python, rsa, ini

I'm using rsa and read key from ini file

```
public_key = rsa.PublicKey(config['public_key.n'],config['public_key.e'])
```

But I receive this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'int'
```

Here is my ini file content

```
[RSA]
public_key.n = 183123867919799980745597191341507205007 
public_key.e = 65537 
private_key.d = 73725121001326311644202607901943421673 
private_key.p = 216949189269184531091 
private_key.q = 844086435799421077
```

I read ini file successful (I printed it in console). Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

ConfigParser (or other methods of access to the ini file) returns strings, not integers. You can either convert those before creating the key

```
public_key = rsa.PublicKey(int(config['public_key.n']),int(config['public_key.e']))
```

or get the values with RawConfigParser.getint when reading the file.